# How do you override a decorator parameter in a sub-template using Thymeleaf Layout Dialect

Tags: thymeleaf

I am using Thymeleaf Layout Dialect.

I have a "defaultLayout" template where the title element is defined like this:

```
<title layout:title-pattern="$DECORATOR_TITLE" 
           th:text="${pageTitle}">Page Title</title>
```

where `pageTitle` is a variable passed from a sub template ("home.html") like this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
  xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
  layout:decorator="defaultLayout"
  th:with="pageTitle='Home'">
```

So far so good. However I now want to "extend" the "home.html" template ("foo.html"). For example:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
  xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
  layout:decorator="home"
  th:with="pageTitle='Foo'">
```

The problem is that when "foo.html" is rendered, it gets the page title "Home" instead of "Foo".

Is Thymeleaf at fault here? Shouldn't it replace the "pageTitle" property with "Foo"? Is there an better way of doing this that I have missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is the following

In `home.html` change the `html` part to:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
  xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
  layout:decorator="defaultLayout"
  th:with="${null != pageTitle ? pageTitle : 'Home'}">
```